# SQL Server 2008 R2 : DDL trigger (ALTER_TABLE) and CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF

Tags: triggers, sql-server-2008-r2, ddl

I'm using a DDL trigger to monitor table structure changes (`ALTER_TABLE`) and update a flag into a table. My application has `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF` and I can't change it. With this setting `OFF`, the trigger below errors out when adding a new column to the table. With it set to `ON`, it works fine.

Any ideas what to do?

> Msg 1934, Level 16, State 1, Procedure TableChangeTracking, Line 50
>   SELECT failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: 'CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL'. Verify that SET options are
>   correct for use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns
>   and/or filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data
>   type methods and/or spatial index operations.

Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TableChangeTracking] 
ON DATABASE 
FOR ALTER_TABLE 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @data XML;
DECLARE @object sysname;

SET @data = EVENTDATA();
SET @object = @data.value( N'(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  N'sysname') 

IF @object IS NOT NULL
    update AUDIT_TABLES set NEED_TRIGGER_UPDATE =  N'Y' where TABLE_NAME = @object
END;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this. I added

> SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON

at the beginning and

> SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF

at the end of the trigger body.

Code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [TableChangeTracking] 
ON DATABASE 
FOR ALTER_TABLE 
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON;

    DECLARE @data XML;
    DECLARE @object sysname;

    SET @data = EVENTDATA();
    SET @object = @data.value( N'(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]',  N'sysname') 

    IF @object IS NOT NULL
        update RS_AUDIT_TABLES set NEED_TRIGGER_UPDATE =  N'Y' where TABLE_NAME = @object

    SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL OFF;
END;
GO
```